# HTTP Uploads with Resource Forks

Tags: php, upload, ftp, fork

I'm building a PHP based upload service for some of our clients.  I am using SWFUpload so that I can view the progress of a file as it uploads.  I've got it pretty much built, but am running into one last issue before we can release it to the public.

Many (almost all) of our clients are Mac-based and are uploading sets of files that include InDesign Files, Fonts, Illustrator Files, etc.  Most of the times the images files are OK, but occasionally (and always with Type 1 Fonts) the file will become corrupted because it is losing the resource fork.

I understand why this is happening (moving from a multi-fork system to a single-fork system), but I can not find any elegant solution.  In my research the best answer I've found so far is "have the user compress it".  I know that works, but it's unreasonable - in our client's opinion - for us to require them to compress every set of files they are going to send.

Are there any better solutions for keeping those resource forks alive?  Of course, I would prefer a solution that is straight javascript/php, but would settle for something that is flash based or (least preferably) java based.

My only requirements for the new solution would be:

- View upload progress
- User doesn't have to manually compress files

Here's some information about my system

- Ubuntu 10.10 Server running a standard LAMP install
- PHP5
- SWFUpload (wtv the most recent version is)

Comment: In ancient times Apple did have file formats called MacBinary and BinHex and AppleSingle... these were specifically encoded to contain all forks in one file... don't know though whether there is an option enable that in current browsers... current mail clients still have support for this sort of thing

Comment: check what happen with a normal upload (no swfupload etc.) - perhaps the browser send the resource fork as a separate MIME part in the POST...

Answer (score 6):

Uploads handle files. If the browser and the underlying OS is not able to deal with forks in this procedure (map anything file onto the file model for uploads), then you're bound to what you get by the systems architecture.

> [Resource fork:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork) The resource fork is a construct of the Mac OS operating system used to store structured data in a file, alongside unstructured data stored within the data fork. A resource fork stores information in a specific form, such as icons, the shapes of windows, definitions of menus and their contents, and application code (machine code).

If that's a blocker to you you might have chosen the wrong field to work in. Just saying, if you run into systematic borders, there is not much you can do about. Even if you work for graphic designers and mac users.

The [swfupload would need a feature to deal with forks](http://www.swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/1461). For that, [flash would need a feature to deal with forks](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/17_Networking_and_communications_7.html). For that [the browser would eventually need a feature to deal with forks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php#29151). And so on.

Next to this chain, another question remains: How to deal with forks? As the upload only maps one file to a chunk of binary data, how to map the fork as well? Append it? Add an additional file?

So on the technical level this does not sound like easily solveable. All components and systems in the file input chain must support a feature that is commonly not supported at all.

So as you can not offer something to the user that does not exist, the only thing you can do is make your application more usable or user-friendly. E.g. by providing the right notes at the right time (e.g. when a user selects a Type 1 file for uploading, to remind him/her to select the fork as well). Communicating with the user can help, but keep in mind that a user needs to be spoken with in a language he/she understands.

So if you know that certain file types have forks, address the issue to someone who can solve it: The user. You can't.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use swfupload to monitor progress.

Here are some file that demonstrate this: https://github.com/senica/Booger/tree/master/assets/js/jquery-upload

It is not documented very well, but it basically uses webkitSlice function for uploading the files in javascript.  You can use the callback functions to display the progress of the files.

This would be a javascript/php solution.